# how to trigger a function automatically in ember.js action helper?

Tags: ember.js, action

I am new to ember.js and working on an application to highlight text like below:

```
<div>
  <h3 class = "title" {{action "highlight" "title"}}>{{document.title}}</h3>
  <div class = "date" {{action "highlight" "date"}}>{{document.date}}</div>
  <p class = "content" {{action "highlight" "content"}}>{{document.contents}}
  </p>
</div>
```

I created a function highlight which will get the class name and highlight the search text the user input. This function works fine, but I have to click to trigger this highlight function. Is there any way in ember action helper can trigger this function whenever the div node rendered or automatically triggered?

Comment: if you still have questions maybe show us the code of the `highlight` action.

Answer (score 2):

What you probably need is to implement the hook `didInsertElement`, this will trigger as soon your component got rendered in the screen.

Example:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
export default Component.extend({
    didInsertElement() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        const title = this.element.querySelector('.title');
        // do something with the title
    },
});
```

More information about didInsertElement can be found in this guide: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.18.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your use-case entirely, but I think actions are not a good choice for your problem. I would recommend reading the ember guides about [computed properties](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.5.0/object-model/computed-properties/). These properties are recomputed everytime an underlying property changes.

```
  highlightedContent: computed('userInput', 'content', function() {
    ....
    //return computedContent;
  })
```

I would also recommend reading the guides about [handlebar-helpers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.5.0/templates/writing-helpers/). You could write a highlight-helper.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. Let check it out.